# Yet another "LaTeX Error: File '***.sty' not found" question

Tags: lyx, packages, mactex

My apologies for what is probably a duplicate question, but I've looked through similar queries, and I either can't make head nor tail of them or they haven't helped me (likely due to my own lack of understanding; I'm very, very new to LaTeX).

I'm running LyX on Mac OS X Yosemite, using the full download of MacTeX (not BasicTeX), and I'm trying to use the package handlatex (`http://handlatex.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html`).  When I type `\usepackage {hand}` (or `\usepackage{hand}` or `\usepackage[]{hand};` not sure whether they're equivalent or not) into the LaTeX preamble in LyX and attempt to preview my document as a `.pdf`, I get the error message "`LaTeX Error: File 'hand.sty' not found,`" with the description "
 `^^M`

`*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)"`

I've run LaTeX on the hand.def, hand.dtx, and hand.ins (hand.ins first, followed by hand.def and hand.dtx), and then moved all of the resulting files produced to the following filepath:
  `Macintosh HD/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local`.  These files are: hand.aux, hand.dvi, hand.sty, hand.log, and hand.out.

...And that's about it.  I think I've got the correct filepath and have dealt with the package correctly, and I believe I've installed the prerequisite python module correctly, running setup.py as instructed and receiving no error messages, so I think the problem is with LaTeX or LyX.  What that problem is, though, I can't fathom, and as again I'm extremely new to LaTeX and LyX (having downloaded both specifically to try to use the handlatex package), I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the hand.sty file to the same location where your own .tex file is located. Additionally, there are some fixed folders where LaTeX looks for .sty files. I'm not using OS X myself, but it should be in:

```
/Users/<user name>/Library/texmf/tex/latex/local/
```

Source: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)